# Blend4Web: Change mesh material

Tags: blend4web

Is there a way to use the Blend4Web Javascript library to change the image texturemap of a mesh after page load?

Comment: Please provide more information: screenshots, code, details, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet:

```
var m_scenes  = require("scenes");
var m_tex = require("textures");

var cube = m_scenes.get_object_by_name("Cube");
m_tex.change_image(cube, "Texture", "./test.png");
```

See also this example to get an idea how to change textures in runtime:

https://www.blend4web.com/apps/code_snippets/code_snippets.html?scene=change_image

Comment: Please give more insight directly in your answer: a link won't necessarily always be there, but the text in your answer will.